# Access denied after installing mysql on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I've been try to install mysql on my Ubuntu 22, considering that i follow some code from my instructor like this o

```
sudo mysql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
quit
```

After that i try to re open mysql and showing error like this

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

what should i do?

Comment: Use the highly secure password of `root` when accessing mysql. `mysql -u root -proot`. Maybe [SET PASSWORD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-password.html) to something more secure once you have logged in. For password resets, see [this manual page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql -u  - p
After that you please input your password